# Change input field's placeholder to either last value submitted or zero

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Hello I have a form that looks like this

```
<form method="post">
    <input type='text' name='amount' placeholder='10,000'>
    <br>
    <input type='submit' name="btn_calculate" value='Calculate'>
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['btn_calculate'])) {
        //validation and calculation
    }
?>
```

And I need the text field to change its placeholder after submitting the form (after the calculation). Either I change it to the last value submitted or to "0"

This is what I have so far:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('[name=btn_calculate]').click(function() { 
        var $this = jQuery('[name=amount]'); 
        $this.attr("placeholder", "0"); 
    });
});
```

But it only changes to 0 for a couple of seconds then goes back to the original placeholder after a while. I've no idea yet how to change it to the last value submitted so I just tried replacing it with 0 first. Any suggestions on how to do these the right way? Or what's wrong with my code?

I tried replacing the `.click` to `.submit` but it wasn't even replacing the placeholder at all.

Comment: change your `input type to button instead of submit`. or add `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Somebody just actually gave an answer a while ago and I just tried out their code and it works perfectly but now they deleted their answer and I didn't even see their username??? It's an inline php code on the input field please put your answer back, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

After you submit the form the page refreshes and it doe not know the last submitted valu as javascript is client based.

Solution:
You need last value submitted in place holder so you need to store the value in **local storage** of browser and then retrieve the value from local storage and put it in placeholder.

Just try storing value in local storage and retrieve it and put this value in place holder.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually tried using PHP sessions to get it everytime but the placeholder doesn't update until after I refresh the page again.

Comment: try using local storage and I hope this would help as the browser will have the value and you can retrieve it and further use it as per your requirement Kindly let me know if u face any problem implementing this

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the javascript changes the placeholder then the php reload the page with the amount in post, but with default value '10000'
you either need to change your submit into a simple button which won't send the variable in POST
or you either need to not use javascript and use the POST variable as your placeholder

Comment: Exactly, I need that to send my form. Thanks

Comment: `<input type='text' name='amount' placeholder="<?=$_POST['btn_calculate']?>">` with an if(isset()) clause before can work